# Can't set up RLS on my locally run supabase in docker

Tags: python, supabase

I am learning supabase in python and I am stuck on this RLS for 3 days. I run it locally inside a supabase docker container. I am trying to insert a file to my `test` bucket that I have created inside the supabase studio. I want to have a RLS for authenticated users.

My code is:

```py
from supabase import create_client
supabase = create_client("http://127.0.0.1:54321", "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJzdXBhYmFzZS1kZW1vIiwicm9sZSI6ImFub24iLCJleHAiOjE5ODM4MTI5OTZ9.CRXP1A7WOeoJeXxjNni43kdQwgnWNReilDMblYTn_I0")
supabase.auth.sign_up({
  "email": 'example@email.com',
  "password": 'example-password',
})
res = supabase.auth.sign_in_with_password({"email":"example@email.com","password":"example-password"})
# 2023-12-18 23:22:23,708:INFO - HTTP Request: POST http://127.0.0.1:54321/auth/v1/token?grant_type=password "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
with open('example.txt', 'rb') as f:
   supabase.storage.from_("test").upload(file=f, path="test")
# 2023-12-18 23:22:34,425:INFO - HTTP Request: POST http://127.0.0.1:54321/storage/v1/object/test/test "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request"
# StorageException: {'statusCode': 400, 'error': 'Unauthorized', 'message': 'new row violates row-level security policy'}
```

The policy:

```
CREATE POLICY "insert auth" ON "storage"."objects"
AS PERMISSIVE FOR INSERT
TO authenticated

WITH CHECK (true)
```

Also:

```
supabase.auth.get_session()
#Session(provider_token=None, provider_refresh_token=None, access_token='eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.zVIwzn1NYG0Guhi41DvDz9FQNGBlec08mr0RPnXypyo', refresh_token='0wZVpAmMzdMc_qzvpgVjvg', expires_in=3600, expires_at=1702941743, token_type='bearer', user=User(id='db32e318-9f9a-4c5c-9a43-1d2aa0168066', app_metadata={'provider': 'email', 'providers': ['email']}, user_metadata={}, aud='authenticated', confirmation_sent_at=None, recovery_sent_at=None, email_change_sent_at=None, new_email=None, invited_at=None, action_link=None, email='admin@email.com', phone='', created_at=datetime.datetime(2023, 12, 18, 14, 43, 57, 392982, tzinfo=TzInfo(UTC)), confirmed_at=datetime.datetime(2023, 12, 18, 14, 43, 57, 397211, tzinfo=TzInfo(UTC)), email_confirmed_at=datetime.datetime(2023, 12, 18, 14, 43, 57, 397211, tzinfo=TzInfo(UTC)), phone_confirmed_at=None, last_sign_in_at=datetime.datetime(2023, 12, 18, 22, 22, 23, 703636, tzinfo=TzInfo(UTC)), role='authenticated', updated_at=datetime.datetime(2023, 12, 18, 22, 22, 23, 704983, tzinfo=TzInfo(UTC)), identities=[UserIdentity(id='db32e318-9f9a-4c5c-9a43-1d2aa0168066', user_id='db32e318-9f9a-4c5c-9a43-1d2aa0168066', identity_data={'email': 'admin@email.com', 'sub': 'db32e318-9f9a-4c5c-9a43-1d2aa0168066'}, provider='email', created_at=datetime.datetime(2023, 12, 18, 14, 43, 57, 396238, tzinfo=TzInfo(UTC)), last_sign_in_at=datetime.datetime(2023, 12, 18, 14, 43, 57, 396220, tzinfo=TzInfo(UTC)), updated_at=datetime.datetime(2023, 12, 18, 14, 43, 57, 396238, tzinfo=TzInfo(UTC)))], factors=None))
```

Comment: It is not implemented in python. There is a workaround but it sucks. [link](https://github.com/supabase-community/supabase-py/discussions/391)